# How to Add a Semi Transparent UIView to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, transparency, xib

Upon a certain user action, I wish to add to my UIViewController another UIView that will be half transparent; i.e. when it loads, the UIViewController view in the back will still be visible in the background, and the new UIView will appear as a layer above it.

The "Half Transparent" UIView should have several images and buttons in it, so I prefer to create a separated h, m and xib files for it so I can control it.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Subclass UIView, create the nib file
2. Change the nib class to your custom subclass name
3. Change the file owner to become your view controller
4. In your view controller, declare a @property for the custom view using IBOutlet
5. Select the nib, drag from the file owner to the custom view and connect the outlet
6. In your button action, when you are ready to load the view, use

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibName" owner:self options:nil];`

Once this is done, your custom will be loaded from the nib and assigned to the property you declared.

Comment: Thanks Rog. A question: when I call transparentView from my firstView - are there any other actions I need to do before loadNibNamed? like "alloc", "initWithFrame", etc...

Comment: When you run `loadNibNamed` your view is "alloc'd / init'd" with the `initWithCoder` method. The frame is set to the size you specify in your nib file. If you need to configure any variables etc during init you can override `initWithCoder` in your custom view class.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view setAlpha:0.5];
[mainview addSubview:view]
```